# How to detect connection close using WS in Playframework with a persistent connection?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi I am doing an app that connects to the Twitter Streaming API and I am using WS to make the connection like this

```
WS.url(endpoint).withTimeout(-1).sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, accessToken)).postAndRetrieveStream(parameters)(processResponse(_))

def processResponse(headers: ResponseHeaders) = {
   Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { chunk =>
     val chunkString = new String(chunk, "UTF-8")
     println(chunkString)
   }
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to detect if the connection has been closed by Twitter

Thanks!

Comment: I realized that setting timeout to -1 makes the connection alive for ever and if for example the network connection is lost there is no way getting notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val future: Future[Unit] = WS.url(endpoint).withTimeout(-1).sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, accessToken)).postAndRetrieveStream(parameters)(processResponse(_))

def processResponse(headers: ResponseHeaders) = {
  Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { chunk =>
    val chunkString = new String(chunk, "UTF-8")
    println(chunkString)
  } 
}

future.map { _ =>
  println("done")
}
```